# String.split causing linebreak on last index

Tags: java, string

When I split my string I get a linebreak after the last index, does anyone know what is causing this?

Code:

```
String string = "1234324:Kalle"

public void splitString(String string){
    if (string.contains(":")) {
        String[] parts = string.split(":");
        returnedId = parts[0];
        returnedUserName = parts[1];
        System.out.println(returnedUserName + " this gets printed on a new line");
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("String " + string + " does not contain :");
    }
}
```

This is causing some unwanted issues in my UI, is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: This code does not produce a newline in the `returnedUserName`. Are you sure this is the code you are running? Perhaps `string` has a newline at its end originally?

Comment: Perform a check for newline in the original string and remove it.

Comment: I too tried the code and there is no new line except for the ones due to println ofcourse.

Comment: Yup you are right, its from the server, no idea why, but it works now with T McKeown's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this before you split:

```
string = string.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\t)", "");
```

This will remove any CRLF or TAB ASCII chars.

Answer (score 1):

#### Why is it doing this?

There is almost certainly a newline following a colon in your *input*.

#### How can I fix it?

[`String.split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a *regular expression*. You could **consume** (optional) white space around the colon, like

```
String[] parts = string.split("\\s*:\\s*");
```